# DataGridView special coloring - which way is better styles or cellformatting event?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm wondering for efficiency which is a better way to do the datagridview cell coloring?

You can use styles set on the grid at design time. I don't use these often though for some reason.

or

you can handle the cellformatting event of every single cell in the grid and do comparisions.

I do not know how the styles check and apply the style but if it makes less calls than a cell formatting event for every single cell it would seem that it is better. I wasn't sure so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CellFormatting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event is indeed an expensive option, as it is called for every visible cell each time it is painted: setting a style is easier I find if you do it in code:

```
     DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            BackColor = Color.White,
            ForeColor = Color.Black,
            SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224),
            SelectionForeColor = Color.Black,
            WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False,
            NullValue = string.Empty
        };

      myDGV.DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
      myDGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Comment: one of the reasons I use cellformatting event is because I look at the value in the cell and according to the value I set one of three different backcolors. How can I accomplish something similar with a style? I was looking at the class and wasn't sure how I would pull that off?

Comment: You're right, for that particular scenario you need to use CellFormatting. You could cache styles with the appropriate BackColor and apply them in the event, it might help performance.